# Prettier is not repecting the tslint rules

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, tslint, prettier

Prettier vsCode extension is not respecting the tslint rules.

tslint.json

```
{
  "extends": ["tslint:recommended"],
  "defaultSeverity": "warn",
  "rulesDirectory": ["codelyzer"],
  "rules": {
    "array-type": false,
    "arrow-parens": false,
    "import-blacklist": [true, "rxjs/Rx"],
    "max-line-length": [true, 140],
    "interface-name": false,
    "max-classes-per-file": false,
    "member-access": false,
    "member-ordering": [
      true,
      {
        "order": [
          "static-field",
          "instance-field",
          "static-method",
          "instance-method"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "no-consecutive-blank-lines": false,
    "no-console": [true, "debug", "info", "time", "timeEnd", "trace"],
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-inferrable-types": [true, "ignore-params"],
    "no-non-null-assertion": true,
    "no-redundant-jsdoc": true,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-use-before-declare": true,
    "no-var-requires": false,
    "object-literal-key-quotes": [true, "as-needed"],
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "ordered-imports": false,
    "quotemark": [true, "single"],
    "trailing-comma": false,
    "no-output-on-prefix": true,
    "use-input-property-decorator": true,
    "use-output-property-decorator": true,
    "use-host-property-decorator": true,
    "no-input-rename": true,
    "no-output-rename": true,
    "use-life-cycle-interface": true,
    "use-pipe-transform-interface": true,
    "component-class-suffix": true,
    "directive-class-suffix": true
  }
}
```

vscode settings

```
{
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "prettier.tslintIntegration": true
}
```

Example: `quotemark` is single, defined by the tslint. Once the prettier invoked, doesn't take care of the quotes.

Before Prettier is the same after

[image]

So any idea how to configure Prettier in order to interact with tsLint?

> I know many articles explain that, But doesn't work for me!

Comment: https://github.com/prettier/tslint-config-prettier

Comment: @Avin Kavish I tired that but doesn't work

Comment: Can you be more specific about "but doesn't work"? What did you do to try it out? What happened or didn't happen?